# No code coverage in TFS build after 2015 upgrade

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

We were using TFS and VS 2013, everything was working fine. We upgraded to TFS and VS 2015. We added a new build server (Windows Server 2012 R2, Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, DevExpress and Wix) to have a clean install.

The builds were failing `Task could not find "LC.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" ...` so we changed the build template from DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml to TfvcTemplate.12.xaml

Now it's building, but when we open the builds from the build explorer under code coverage we have `No build code coverage data available.` Code coverage is enabled in the build definition.

Comment: Can you move to the new agents in 2015? The old legacy xaml build system is deprecated.

Comment: @MrHinsh Didn't look yet at how long or difficult it will be. We also have a project to consolidate TFS servers company wide starting, I don't want to modify too much now. Any link to official MS documents saying it's deprecated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you enabled Code coverage by going to the **process** tab of the build definition and then expanding the **Tests--Automated tests--Test Source--Run settings**, and change the **Type of run settings** from **Default** to **CodeCoverageEnabled**.

I have tried the same steps in TFS 2015, and I can't get Code coverage either in this way.

Instead, I tried the steps below, then I can get Code coverage now:

1. Go to **Process--Test--Automated tests--Test source** in build definition.
2. Now in **Test source** row, click the button with "**...**".
3. Under "**Options**", select **Enabled Code Coverage** and save the build definition. No matter the **Enabled Code Coverage** option has been selected or not, you still need to save this edit. Now queue the build, you'll see the code coverage.

[image]

Comment: Works OK now. I went back to Default in Type of run settings and saved, then set Enable Code Coverage in Test source > Options and this put back CodeCoverageEnabled in Type of run settings.